# There's duplicated query result in Microsoft Access while checking for time overlapping

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I got a table with a huge list of equipment booking details. I wrote a SQL Query to display the desired result that I wanted: A type of the equipment with time overlapping of booking.

So I check for the time overlapping by duplicating my table in order for it to check against each other.

The result I gotten are kind of repetitive?
For instance,
May CLASHES Claire
**May CLASHES Sherene**
Claire CLASHES May
**Claire CLASHES Sherene**
Sherene CLASHES May

Those in bold are repetitive.
How can I modify my SQL query in order to resolve the issue?
Please kindly advise. Thank you!

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM 2015, 2015 AS 2015_1 
WHERE ([2015].Equipment Like '*Video cam*' Or [2015].Equipment Like '*video recorder*' Or [2015].Equipment Like '*camcorder*')
AND ([2015_1].Equipment Like '*Video cam*' Or [2015_1].Equipment Like '*video recorder*' Or [2015_1].Equipment Like '*camcorder*')
AND ([2015].[Loaned By]<>[2015_1].[Loaned By]) 
AND ([2015_1].[Start Time]<=[2015].[End Time]) 
AND ([2015_1].[End Time] Is Null Or [2015_1].[End Time]>=[2015].[Start Time]);
```

**EDIT**
My table is called 2015. 
The variables are (Field Name - Data Type):
ID - Number
Loaned By - Text
Equipment - Text
Start Date - Date/Time
Start Time - Date/Time
End Date - Date/Time
End Time - Date/Time
Durations (hours) - Number

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following condition:

```
[2015].EquipmentType < [2015_1].EquipmentType
```

This will order them alphabetically.

Your question doesn't have enough information to clearly specify the column.

Comment: `WHERE ([2015].Equipment Like '*Video cam*' Or [2015].Equipment Like '*video recorder*' Or [2015].Equipment Like '*camcorder*')
AND ([2015_1].Equipment Like '*Video cam*' Or [2015_1].Equipment Like '*video recorder*' Or [2015_1].Equipment Like '*camcorder*')` Helped me to filter out the type of equipment I want to display in my query result. Hold on, I will modifiy the question to include the variables.